# Ineer Join query with where in scala slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have two tables address ,UserAddressMapping
 in Adress table Adrressid ,Address is there and in the third table i mapped this userid and Addresss id

In sql

```
Select a.Addressid,a.AddressNmae 
from address table a 
inner join UserAdrressmaping b on a.Adessressid=b.Adreesid 
where userid=1
```

How to write this thing in Scala slick
 This is far what i have done

```
   def innerJoin1(UserId:Int): Future[Seq[UserRegister]]  =  {
 val join=address.join(addressid).on(_.Userid === _.UserId)

    dbConfig.run(join.result )
  }
```

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself before? Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inner join you could use slick [applicative-join](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/queries.html#applicative-joins) with filter clause.
For example:

```
val query = for {
  (address, userAddressMapping) <- Address join UserAddressMapping on (_.id === _.addressId)
  if userAddressMapping.userId === 1
} yield (address.id, address.name)

dbConfig.run(query.result)
```

Comment: def GetPractionerInfo(Horse_id:Int):Future[Seq[(String,String)]]=
{
  val qNested =       for{
        ((p,e),c) <-
          users.join(horsepractionermapp).on(_.id == _.userid)
            .join(users1).on(
            _._2.horseid===_.HorseID
          )
    if e.horseid===Horse_id
      } yield(p.Name, c.HorseName)
 dbConfig.run(qNested.result)

}      i am getting exception in this query

Comment: i am geeting this exception "inferred type arguments [Boolean] do not conform to method on's type parameter bounds [T <: slick.lifted.Rep[_]]"

Comment: hi that exception is gone now but m not getting response in proper format means Header is not coming properly in response "[{"_1":"Abhinay","_2":"chetak"}]" in place of _1 i want Name and in place of _2 i want horsename how to do that

Comment: You should map result to case class to archive that - https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html

Comment: here i am joining three tables and these are defines in different case  classes

Comment: You are returning only 2 fields. For that you can create separate case class and map result to it

Comment: Can you help me in mapping my result with case class this is my new case class"case class MappingData(HorseName:String,OwnerName:String)"

Comment: Something like `dbConfig.run(query.result).map(MappingData.tupled)` or more explicitly `dbConfig.run(query.result).map(res => MappingData(res._1, res._2))` should work

Comment: Nope it's not working it's saying "value _1 is not a member of Seq[(String, String)]"

Comment: For sequence you need to iterate over each element and map it: `db.run(...).map(res => res.map(tuple => MappingData(tuple._1, tuple._2)))`

Comment: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Module.MappingData]
 required: Seq[(String, String)]

Comment: do you have any solution for this query "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092178/how-to-select-single-column-from-database-using-scala-play2-6"

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the previous one. If you happen to have `BigDecimal` for `Id`, do not forget to cast it:

```
if p.userId === BigDecimal.valueOf(42)
```