# Sending a Mail to Gmail in scala playframework(2.6) slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to send a mail to my gmail account .
i am getting response as "Email Send". But I am not getting any mail.
i am using Scal Playframework(2.6)

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer-guice" % "6.0.0"
```

This is far what i have done

Controller Class

```
package controllers
import play.api.libs.mailer._
import java.io.File
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import play.api.Environment
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import play.api.libs.mailer._
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, Action, Controller, ControllerComponents}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpHeader.ParsingResult.Ok
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.libs.json.Json
class MailController  @Inject()(mailer: MailerClient, environment: Environment) extends Controller {

  def sendWithCustomMailer = Action {
  //  val mailer = new SMTPMailer(SMTPConfiguration("typesafe.org", 1234))
   // val id = mailer.send(Email("Simple email", "Mister FROM <abhinaykumar499@gmail.com>"))

    val emailfrom="xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    val emailto="yyyyyyyyy@gmail.com"
val subject ="Simple Email"
    val bodytext="A text message";

    val email = Email("Simple email", ""+emailfrom+"", Seq(""+emailto+""), bodyText = Some("A text message"))
    mailer.send(email)

    Ok(s"Email  sent!")
  }
```

And I have added this in my Application.conf

```
play.mailer {
  smtp.host = "smtp.gmail.com" // (mandatory)
  port = 465// (defaults to 25)
  ssl = true  // (defaults to no)
  tls = false // (defaults to no)
  tlsRequired =false // (defaults to no)
  user = "xxxxxx@gmail.com" // (optional)
  password = "12121212" // (optional)
 // debug = false // (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout = 600 // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout = 600 // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock = true // (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to start by enabling the debug on the conf

Comment: have you followed the instructions at https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#usage ? namely the 'Then you need to register the MailerComponents trait in your main Components file' part

Comment: i have followed the same code as mention  at https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#usage but it's not working from me and how  toregister the MailerComponents trait in your main Components file' part

Comment: You have `mock = true` thats mean that mailer service works in test mode. Set this param to false.

Comment: if i am setting mock=false then i am getting exception in " mailer.send(email)" and if am setting mock=true then i am not getting any exception and response i am getting as "Email Sent " but i am not getting any mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wrongly configured host part. You wrote `smtp.host = "smtp.gmail.com"` but correct value is `host = "smtp.gmail.com"`.

In my project working config for google smtp is following:

```
play {
  mailer {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 587
    tls = yes
    user = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    password = "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: if i am using this conf then i am getting exception "
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587]]"

Comment: @Abhinay add `debug=yes` to config to see what is going on. Also if you have antivirus on your PC deactivate it and try to send email again

Comment: Your issue could be related to this https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/issues/115

Comment: Thanks a lot i have uninstalled the Antivirus now it's working

Comment: i have one more doubt in Scala not related to mail issue it's related to inner join of three tables based on some condition and get response as json with header    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910691/ineer-join-query-with-where-in-scala-slick?noredirect=1#comment90784555_51910691