# How to select Single column from database using scala Play2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have one table User details Table and it contains below Columns

User id,username,Email

I want to select email whose user id is 1
and i want the response as in proper JSON Format

How to do that In Scala Play 2.6 with Slick
Till now I have done this

```
 def getPasswqord(username:String):Future[Seq[(String)]]= {
    val a2 = (sql"""select a.userpassword from user_details_table  a where a.Email=$username or a.Mobile_no=$username""".as[(String)])

    dbConfig.run(a2)

    }
```

from this i am getting response in a format `"["12345"]"`.

Expected output format is

```
"[{"Password":"12345"}]"
```

Comment: You van have a look at http://playframework.github.io/anorm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define custom [Json Writes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes) to format your query result.
For example:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, JsValue, Json, Writes}

// Given passwords
val passwords: Seq[(String)] = Seq(("12345"), ("qwerty"))
val writes : Writes[String] = (JsPath \ "password").write[String]

def toJson[T](sequence: Seq[T])(implicit writes: Writes[T]): JsValue = {
  Json.toJson(sequence)
}

toJson(passwords)(writes)
```

This will output json object `[{"password":"12345"},{"password":"qwerty"}]`

Comment: i want that password dynamically  based on some condition  from database

Comment: Call `map` method on `Future` returned from `dbConfig.run(a2)` and transform Strings to JsValue as I've mentioned

Comment: There is no need to define `toJson` as the provided collection `Writes` is already working in this way, and so will be used by `Json.toJson(passwords)`

Comment: @cchantep you are right. It's possible to define `implicit Writes[String]`

Comment: Above thing is working when i want to retrive only Single column but for two columns if  i am writing this "
    implicit   val writes : Writes[String] = ((JsPath \ "Username").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "password").write[String] )" then it's saying "for and         it can't resolve symbol"

Comment: For tuple of two Strings you must define ‘Writes[(String, String)]’ Read docs in my answer for details

Comment: I have tries the same "   implicit   val writes : Writes[(String,String)] = ((JsPath \ "Username").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "password").write[String])"  but i am geeting issues in "And " as it saying can't resolve Symbol for this

Comment: Have you added ‘import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._’?

Comment: yes After importing this i am geeting below exception "type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder[play.api.libs.json.OWrites]#CanBuild2[String,String]
 required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[(String, String)]"

Comment: Add all requirements from the start to get correct answer next time

Comment: @ValeriiRusakov  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318639/how-to-select-multiple-column-from-database-using-scala-play2-6-and-with-proper please find this link